# Disable jshell tab completion

Tags: java, java-11, jshell

I want to know if it is possible to disable tab completion in jshell, looking in jshell --help, it has characteristics for feedback

```
--feedback <mode>     Specify the initial feedback mode. The mode may be
                        predefined (silent, concise, normal, or verbose) or
                        previously user-defined
```

But This do not work for tab completion. it is possible to disable this on jdk 11.0.6

Comment: Do you want to use the tab press for some other purpose? I mean to ask, why do you want to disable?

Comment: Well at the moment, I doesn't have any reason, maybe to execute it inside emacs in a comint buffer or something like this.